# Change default Squash And Merge commit message algorithm

Tags: git, github, git-workflow, git-squash

I want to write CI/CD script, which will change the default generated Squash And Merge commit into the convention my team uses.
 Is it possible to change it in CI/CD level, can I get commit messages in the script and generate a new commit message?
 Can you suggest something that will help me? like articles.

Comment: Could you explain more your workflow? There's no "squash and merge" option in Git, are you referring to GitHub?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to GitHub, which I mentioned in the tags section.

Comment: When the developer opens PR on the master branch, the workflow starts the work, it runs some scrips (linter, tests), and then if everything is ok, it allows to squash and merges.

Comment: So you're asking how to configure the commit message generated by Github after a PR is considered valid (after all your workflows ran succesfully)?

Comment: yes, you undersood

Comment: Seems it's not possible: https://github.community/t/how-to-change-the-default-squash-merge-commit-message/1155/37